# Leaflet marker labels on top of marker

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Leaflet labels are currently rendering under markers. How do I get the labels to render on top of markers?

http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/mapbox/csvmarkers/

```
        marker.bindLabel(marker.toGeoJSON().properties.city + ', ' +
        marker.toGeoJSON().properties.country);
```

[image]

Comment: Answers go in answer blocks. Please don't update questions with answers. The site does not work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks correct to me:

[image]

> Leaflet markers are currently rendering under markers.

Missing a word here?

Comment: Sorry - I was futzing with the app when you were looking at it - apologies. Now you can look again and it will display the problem I presented.  http://i.imgur.com/CxxSaat.jpg

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
this.eachLayer(function(marker) {
L.setOptions(marker, {riseOnHover: true});
```